# Should JSFiddle links be left in when a Stack Snippet is added

Tags: discussion, edits, stack-snippets, jsfiddle

A friend told me they had posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285528/focusout-not-working-after-append-is-called-and-used) on SO and wanted me to look at it.  I did and saw that they didn't include their code in the question at all, including only a link to JSFiddle.  I edited the question by putting the code into the question, removing the JSFiddle and adding a stack snippet.  This edit was approved.  I came back today to look at the question and saw it had been [edited again](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27285528/revisions), the only change being the re-addition of the JSFiddle link.

Should I have left the JSFiddle link in when I added the code and stack snippet?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but in the in the fiddle the button works, in the code-snippet it silently doesn't.

Comment: @Deduplicator it didn't work because I forgot to tell the snippet editor that jquery was going to be used.  I submitted a new edit fixing it (and again removing the JSFiddle link).  I'd still appreciate feedback though

Comment: In my opinion, it should not be removed, even if it is redundant.  Create a *collapsed* snippet with the contents but keep the JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, keep in mind that you can't guarantee something which works in JS Fiddle — or any other specific code hosting service — will work in a Stack Snippet. I would advise against even converting someone else's fiddle into a Stack Snippet unless you can verify that the code still functions as the asker intended. If in doubt, simply add the code into the question (or advise the asker to do so), and leave the external link untouched.

If you can ensure that it does work in a Stack Snippet, and you choose to convert it, then I suppose there really isn't any reason for the external link to remain around, let alone be edited back in.