# Is it OK to edit a users code question to utilize the Runnable Snippets?

Tags: discussion

Is it alright to edit a users posted question/answer that already provides HTML/JS/CSS code so that it is instead used in a Runnable Snippet?  I don't mean changing their code at all, I mean changing a question [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28093178/691711) so that it no longer utilizes the jsFiddle but instead the new native Runnable Snippet on Stack Overflow.

I feel like this might open a can of worms in terms of editing, but I feel like it is a tangible improvement to a question/answer.

Comment: Related: [Should JSFiddle links be left in when a Stack Snippet is added](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278515/should-jsfiddle-links-be-left-in-when-a-stack-snippet-is-added)

Comment: If you're also fixing other problems in the question then it's fine (leave the JSFiddle link just in case the code doesn't behave the same in a Stack Snippet, as BoltClock pointed out), otherwise don't waste your time (and our time because it'll also bump the post to the front page) with such a minor edit.